# initialising a form with data using django on google appengine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have a post handler that uses a 'from google.appengine.ext.db.djangoforms.ModelForm'. It pulls the existing instance the data base then initialises the form by:

```
  myForm = TestForm(instance=self_instance, data=post_data)
```

I'm only putting one of the three properties in the post_data which is being correctly copied to the form but the other two properties which already have values in the 'self_instance' are being set to None. Can this be avoided?

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you supply `instance` arg, the form is considered unbound
2. If you supply `data` arg, the form is considered bound

If you supply both, `data` will override `instance` (=> same as case 2, form bound).

So in your case, it's better to load `self_instance` then update it with `data` and then use the unbound form:

```
myForm = TestForm(instance=self_instance)
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying that. Is there a simple way to update the data?

Answer (score 2):

This is giving me the behaviour I'm after:

```
if self_instance:
  logging.info('creating form with instance so updating the post data, we need this to bind the form so we can validate it')
  if post_data:
    #update the post data with existing values
    for prop in self_instance._properties:
      if prop not in post_data:
        cur_prop_val = getattr(self_instance, prop)
        if isinstance(cur_prop_val,db.Model):
          str(cur_prop_val.key())
        else:
          post_data[prop] = cur_prop_val
  else:
    logging.info('no post data so not adding it to form')
  form_data = form_class(data=post_data,instance=self_instance)
else:
  logging.info('creating form without instance')
  form_data = form_class(data=post_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your form definition. But, generally, if you don't want to include fields in the form, you should specify them in the Meta `exclude` tuple - then they won't be overwritten by non-existent POST data.

Comment: thanks for your answer, sorry if I didn't clarify the question. I don't want exclude any fields, I'm posting from a thick client but it's only one of the three parameters. The default behaviour seems to be setting everything else to None but I want to remember the instance values that are present for the other two fields.